# Apache mod_rewrite matches partial filename and returns 404

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been away for a month, and my testing server restarted after a power out, probably with an updated version of apache (2.4.7) and mod_rewrite. Now my `.htaccess` file has a strange behaviour on this test server, but not on the live server.

The following URL's gives "200 OK" on the live server, but not on the test server. There it matches partial file names, up to the period, and gives a "404 Not found"

```
http://192.168.1.1/travel/ - 200 OK
http://192.168.1.1/travel/map/ - 200 OK
http://192.168.1.1/travel/index - 404 Not found
http://192.168.1.1/travel/index.php - 200 OK
http://192.168.1.1/travel/Trip - 404 Not found
http://192.168.1.1/travel/Tri - 200 OK
http://192.168.1.1/travel/trip - 200 OK
http://192.168.1.1/travel/User/yyy/zzz - 404 Not found
http://192.168.1.1/travel/user/yyy/zzz - 200 OK
http://192.168.1.1/travel/Test - 200 OK
```

This is my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 10M
```

Here is my `travel` directory structure:

```
images/
map/index.php
.htaccess
Blog.class.php
Location.class.php
Trip.class.php
Image.class.php
index.php
User.class.php
```

The test server is run on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because URL's on some servers and *nix servers are case sensitive.

Try adding the `NC flag` to see if that helps.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [NC,L]
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_nc

Or you might also try turning of Multiviews, placing this at the top.

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Comment: Did not work! It was run on a Linux server before the update and the live server is a *NIX server too.

Comment: Let me ask you, none of these requests are real directories or files?

Comment: `travel` is a directory, so is `travel/map` and `travel/index.php` is a file. The `.htaccess` file resides in the directory `travel`. I updated the question with more examples. The match seems to be up to the period in the file name

Comment: Try turning off multiviews. Put this at the top. `Options -MultiViews`

Comment: This worked! Please make an answer of this, so I can reward you!